# Date filter not executing

Tags: sql, shell

I'm trying to run a Unix script with embedded SQL query to extract a number of listed records in various tables.

The initial Shell script with query which was working successfully was like this:

```
if [ "$Domain" = "S{Domain123}" ]; then
squery="SELECT id, nid, pnos, accno, dtyp, FROM Table1 WHERE id IN(SELECT uid FROM Table2 WHERE Type=$Utyp1)"
fi
```

I needed to include recorddate column and date filter into the query as per requirement shown below:

```
"SELECT id, nid, pnos, accno, dtyp, Rdate FROM Table1 WHERE id IN(SELECT uid FROM Table2 WHERE Type=$Utyp1) AND Rdate >= '$(date -d("01-Jan-2022" +'%d-%b-%y')';"
```

This query is fetching the records with a recorddate column but the date filter is not implemented during extraction. All the available records are fetched irrespective of the recorddate.

When I run the log output of the query which comes as below, In SQL developer the query extracts the records in the desired manner.. but fails when executed from the shell script.

Log output:

```
select id, nid, pnos, accno, dtyp, Rdate FROM Table1 WHERE id IN(select uid from Table2 where Type=$Utyp1) and Rdate >= '01-Jan-22';
```

p.s:

1. The date format stored in the table is dd-mmm-yy as per client requirements (Non ISO kind) hence I  used the same formatting.
2. I also tried using " Rdate BETWEEN '01-Jan-22' AND '31-Mar-23'; " method.. but still the behavior is same as before.

Someone please guide me to resolve the error.

TIA.

Comment: and what ios your shell script, you probably only send one parameter, but without code nobody can help you

Comment: Thank you.
Edited the original post with shell script details. Hope that is sufficient.

Comment: twhere did you define $Utyp1  it seems to be missing i your code

Comment: Called out from Global variables.

Comment: the variable was not replaced, so it doesn't exist in that scope, as i said without seeing more it us hard to tell